# jquery autocomplete will not display data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

Forgive me if I do not use the correct terms, I am a beginner at this and I am trying to build my own dynamic website. My problem is with jquery autocomplete. I cannot get it to display data on the webpage.
I have been reading forums and watching videos for a week. I have tried dozens of scripts. Nothing seems to work.

This is the jquery that works:

```
 </style>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.11.4-themes- smoothness.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
 $( "#search_bars" ).autocomplete({
source: ['Bob', 'Ted', 'Bruce', 'Alice'],
minLength: 2

});
});
</script>
```

Here is the jquery that does NOT work:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.11.4-themes-smoothness.css">
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
 $( "#search_bars" ).autocomplete({
source: 'js/ajax.php',
minLength: 2

});
});
</script>
```

Here is the ajax.php code:

```
    <?php 
    include_once '../reviews.class2.php';

    $reviews = new Reviews();

    echo json_encode($reviews->search_bars($_GET['term']));

    ?>
```

And finally, here is the reviews.class2.php code:

```
<?php 
require('Connections/db_conn.php');?>
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_db_conn, $db_conn) or die("could not find db");

class  Reviews
{
public function _construct(){
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = 'dbpassword';
    $dbname = 'dbname';

    mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

    mysql_select_db($dbname);


}
public function search_bars($name){
    $data = array();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM listing WHERE Name LIKE '%$name%' OR City LIKE '%$name%' ORDER BY Name LIMIT 10";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $data[] = array("value" => $row['Name'] . ' ' .
                                   $row['City']);
        }

    return $data;
    }
    }
```

When I preview the ajx.php page in the browser, I see the json data as this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: term in C:\xampp\htdocs\js\ajax.php on line 6

[{"value":"88?s Dueling Pianos Hollywood"},{"value":"All Stars Sports Bar and Grill Pompano Beach"},{"value":"America?s Backyard Fort     Lauderdale"},{"value":"American Rock Restaurant Bar and Grill Deerfield Beach"},{"value":"B.E.D. Miami Beach"},{"value":"Bamboo Beach Fort Lauderdale "},{"value":"Bamboo Room Lake Worth"},{"value":"Bardot Miami"},{"value":"Beach Betty?s Dania Beach"}, {"value":"Best Cellar Wilton Manors "}]
```

The problem is that the json data is not showing up in the

Please help!

Comment: plus I think you need to fix that undefined term in ajax.php line 6, autocomplete very picky about json result set, so its seeing that error and not returning anything at all

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar issue until I overrode the autocomplete styles...

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-autocomplete { max-height: 150px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; font-size: 9pt; }
    * html .ui-autocomplete { height: 100px; }
</style>
```